# Bastion on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit gives only a black screen

Tags: 12.04, graphics, 64-bit, games

I just downloaded the Humble Bundle with the game Bastion. After installing Bastion and starting it up, only it shows first a few logos, and then only a black screen and the mouse pointer. I can here the sound fine.

I read a message board that recommended starting it with `-windowed -x 1280 -y 720` which does not work.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, with a Intel 3000 integrated graphics card. Does anyone know how I can get this to work properly?

Comment: I think it's just Linux driver flakiness. I had the same issue on open source Nvidia drivers until I installed the proprietary ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason the -windowed option doesn't work if you start with the shell script bastion64.sh (in /opt/bastion/Bastion as packaged trough the software center) is that the shell script doesn't pass the command line arguments on to the Bastion.bin.x86_64 binary. To fix this, append ' $@' to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib64:. ./Bastion.bin.x86_64' line in the bastion64.sh script. Unfortunately, -windowed is the only way the game works for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This helped me:

```
sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
```

Mike_IronFist said at ubuntuforums.org:

> (Bastion) use S3tc textures and for some reason Intel graphics cards don't use these automatically on Linux.

Thread on the problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11992661

Comment: This package fixed also "Psychonaut", that it wasn't starting before.

Answer (score 0):

If running the steam version, go to the game launcher > right click, properties, press the **select launch options** button, and add this

```
force_s3tc_enable=true
```

That fixed it for me on Ubuntu 14.04.3, x64